# call script tag by using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i am trying to call script alert using ajax for example

i have created two files
test1.php and test2.php

here is my code:

test1.php

Change Content

### Let AJAX change this text

```
<script>

<pre><script>
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "test2.php", true);
xhttp.send();
}
</script>


</pre>
</script>
```

test2.php

```
<pre>
<script>alert('hello');</script>

echo "Hello User";
</pre>
```

the problem is my script tag is not getting called by ajax and is showing blank response . 
please need your help.
Thank You again.

Comment: @JaromandaX Check the duplicate, scripts tags made by innerHTML are not expected to run.

Comment: yeah sorry for the duplicate script tag but the problem still is the same i am unable to call script alert from test2.php

Comment: Why do you put `<pre>` around a script? Scripts aren't rendered, so formatting doesn't matter.

Comment: Can you use jQuery? It will execute scripts when you insert them with `.html()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easily, remove `<script>` and `</script>` from test2.php, then in test1.php change:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

to

```
eval(this.responseText);
```

here is full sample code:

test1.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            eval(this.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "test2.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
}

loadDoc();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and test2.php:

```
alert('hello');
```

Comment: thank you for response but i m still not getting javascript alert from test2.php . Can you please provide me  similar working example if posssible.

Comment: in your javascript you must call loadDoc() function, after creating it.

Comment: thanks a lot , it worked for me. my another question is can i get both javascipt alert and php echo statment together from test2.php for example   : alert('hello user'); and <? php echo "username : sam" ?> like this. Thank you again for helping

Comment: it is possible. there are many ways to do that. but one of them is to create your html and text data in test2.php script. for example you can use: `document.write("hello user");` before alert script